# last_write_time Mismatch on Copied Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, directory, copy

I'm uncertain whether this is a platform difference or an implementation difference. I'm hoping that someone can help me shed light on that. Given this code:

```
filesystem::path foo("foo");
filesystem::path bar("bar");

filesystem::create_directories(foo);

filesystem::copy(foo, bar);

const auto fooftime = filesystem::last_write_time(foo);
const auto barftime = filesystem::last_write_time(bar);
const auto foocftime = decltype(fooftime)::clock::to_time_t(fooftime);
const auto barcftime = decltype(barftime)::clock::to_time_t(barftime);

cout << '(' << foocftime << ')' << asctime(localtime(&foocftime)) << '(' << barcftime << ')' << asctime(localtime(&barcftime)) << (fooftime == barftime) << endl;
```

[gcc outputs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9da89e4b76608d52):

> (1513798777)Wed Dec 20 19:39:37 2017
>   (1513798777)Wed Dec 20 19:39:37 2017
>   1

But Visual Studio will output:

> (1513798819)Wed Dec 20 14:40:19 2017
>   (1513798819)Wed Dec 20 14:40:19 2017
>   0

This seems like `fooftime` and `barftime` are equal, but when I inspect the variables in the Visual Studio debugger they contain more precision than they're outputting, *and they differ in that extended precision*. Can someone help me understand where the breakdown here is?

[image]

Comment: What are the times you see when using the native system commands to inspect the files?  And what type of file-system(s) are you using, different file-system record time with different accuracy?  For example the FAT based file-systems have a time granularity of 2 seconds.

Comment: @RichardCritten Unsurprisingly they both show the exact same time that is output. I don't know of any way to look at the date at a higher granularity than that. I don't really know any reason why there would need to be a higher granularity than that.